# Which adjective would you use in this case?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing to a friend of mine and I can't find a proper word to describe two language-learning courses in Duolingo.

> As for the Duolingo German and Spanish courses, **I find them to be** ...

The message I want to convey is that I think that they took care of every detail while they were making them.

Would you simply say *well-made*? Is there a more proper term to use to talk about the act of caring about the details?

Comment: Perhaps: *meticulously constituted/fashioned*.

Comment: Another one: created with great attention to details. Word of advice: when stuck - try to re-phrase completely. I think your issue is coming from the fact that you trapped yourself in this particular start of the sentence while you had absolutely no issues describing your goal in your last sentence of the question.

Comment: **consistent** may be your word. Or, maybe, something like **excelently constructed** or maybe some other adjective.

Comment: taking care of every detail = *thorough*  or *comprehensive*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all adjectives, there are several options to choose from. You could for example use: "attentive" which means: "Paying close attention to something." - [English Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/attentive)

Since you want to convey an attention to every detail, then perhaps you could try:
"As for the Duolingo German and Spanish courses, I find them to be holistically attentive."

Another adjective that would work is: "meticulous" which means: "Showing great attention to detail; very careful and precise." - [English Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meticulous)

In that case you could for example say: "As for the Duolingo German and Spanish courses, I find them to be wonderfully meticulous in both design and execution."

Note: I added "wonderfully" and "in both design and execution" since to some native speakers, the word "meticulous" has a slightly negative feeling.